# How to split a delimited string into an array in awk?

Tags: awk

How to split the string when it contains pipe symbols `|` in it.
I want to split them to be in array.

I tried

```
echo "12:23:11" | awk '{split($0,a,":"); print a[3] a[2] a[1]}'
```

Which works fine. If my string is like `"12|23|11"` then how do I split them into an array?

Comment: Note that your output is concatenating the array elements, with no separator. If you instead wanted them to be separated with `OFS`, stick commas in between them, making `print` see them as separate arguments.

Comment: Or you can use sed: `echo "12:23:11" | sed "s/.*://"`

Comment: @slushy: your command is not at all what the asker needs. your command ( `echo "12:23:11" | sed "s/.*://"`) delete everything until (and including) the last ":", keeping only the "11" ... it works to get the last number, but would need to be modified (in an difficult to read way) to get the 2nd number, etc.  awk (and awk's split) is much more elegant and readable.

Comment: if you need to split on a single character you can use `cut`

Answer (score 395, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
echo "12|23|11" | awk '{split($0,a,"|"); print a[3],a[2],a[1]}'
```

Comment: is not working for me :( is that because of the length of the string ? since, my string length is 4000. any ideas

Comment: @Mohamed Saligh, if you're on Solaris, you need to use */usr/xpg4/bin/awk*, given the string length.

Comment: 'is not working for me'. especially with colons between the echoed values and split set up to split on '|'??? Typo? Good luck to all.

Comment: Better with some syntax explanation.

Comment: This will not work in GNU awk, because third argument to `split` is regular expression, and `|` is special symbol, which needs to be escaped. Use `split($0, a, "\|")`

Comment: @WhiteWind which version? it works without escaping for me on `GNU Awk 4.1.3` and using `"\|"` actually gives a warning... you'd need `"\\|"`

Comment: How do i assign this values to a variable and access it within the script ?

Comment: @WhiteWind: another way to "ensure" that `|` is seen as a char and not a special symbol is to put it between `[]` :  ie,   `split($0, a, "[|]")`   # I like this better than '\|', in some cases, especially as some variant of regexp (perl vs grep vs .. others?) can have "|" interepreted literally and "\|" seen as regex separator, instead of the opposite...  ymmv

Comment: Awk is dynamite!

Comment: Can use a shorter variant: `echo "a : b : c" | awk -F":" '{print $1 $2 }'` or `echo "a | b | c" | awk -F"|" '{print $1 $2 }'`

Comment: it also supports multiple delimiter: `split($0, a, "[|,]")`  <-- split by either `|` or `,`

Answer (score 206):

To split a string to an array in `awk` we use the function [`split()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-split_0028_0029-function):

```bash
awk '{split($0, array, ":")}'
#           \/  \___/  \_/
#           |     |     |
#       string    |     delimiter
#                 |
#               array to store the pieces
```

---

If no separator is given, it uses the `FS`, which defaults to the space:

```bash
$ awk '{split($0, array); print array[2]}' <<< "a:b c:d e"
c:d
```

We can give a separator, for example `:`:

```bash
$ awk '{split($0, array, ":"); print array[2]}' <<< "a:b c:d e"
b c
```

Which is equivalent to setting it through the `FS`:

```bash
$ awk -F: '{split($0, array); print array[2]}' <<< "a:b c:d e"
b c
```

In GNU Awk you can also provide the separator as a regexp:

```bash
$ awk '{split($0, array, ":*"); print array[2]}' <<< "a:::b c::d e
#note multiple :
b c
```

And even see what the delimiter was on every step by using its fourth parameter:

```bash
$ awk '{split($0, array, ":*", sep); print array[2]; print sep[1]}' <<< "a:::b c::d e"
b c
:::
```

Let's quote the [man page of GNU awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-split_0028_0029-function):

> *split(string, array [, fieldsep [, seps ] ])*
>
> Divide *string* into pieces separated by *fieldsep* and store the pieces in *array* and the separator strings in the *seps* array. The first piece is stored in `array[1]`, the second piece in `array[2]`, and so forth. The string value of the third argument, *fieldsep*, is a regexp describing where to split *string* (much as *FS* can be a regexp describing where to split input records). If *fieldsep* is omitted, the value of *FS* is used. `split()` returns the number of elements created. *seps* is a `gawk` extension, with `seps[i]` being the separator string between `array[i]` and `array[i+1]`. If *fieldsep* is a single space, then any leading whitespace goes into `seps[0]` and any trailing whitespace goes into `seps[n]`, where *n* is the return value of `split()` (i.e., the number of elements in array).

Answer (score 22):

Please be more specific! What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?
Post the exact output (or error message), your OS and awk version:

```
% awk -F\| '{
  for (i = 0; ++i <= NF;)
    print i, $i
  }' <<<'12|23|11'
1 12
2 23
3 11
```

Or, using split:

```
% awk '{
  n = split($0, t, "|")
  for (i = 0; ++i <= n;)
    print i, t[i]
  }' <<<'12|23|11'
1 12
2 23
3 11
```

Edit: on *Solaris* you'll need to use the *POSIX* awk (*/usr/xpg4/bin/awk*) in order to process 4000 fields correctly.

Comment: `for(i = 0` or `for(i = 1` ?

Comment: i = 0, because I use ++i after (not i++).

Comment: Ok - I did not notice this. I strongly believe more readable would be `for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)` ...

Answer (score 9):

I do not like the `echo "..." | awk ...` solution as it calls unnecessary `fork` and `exec`system calls.

I prefer a Dimitre's solution with a little twist

```
awk -F\| '{print $3 $2 $1}' <<<'12|23|11'
```

Or a bit shorter version:

```
awk -F\| '$0=$3 $2 $1' <<<'12|23|11'
```

In this case the output record put together which is a true condition, so it gets printed.

In this specific case the `stdin` redirection can be spared with setting an [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) internal variable:

```
awk -v T='12|23|11' 'BEGIN{split(T,a,"|");print a[3] a[2] a[1]}'
```

I used [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh) quite a while, but in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) this could be managed by internal string manipulation. In the first case the original string is split by internal terminator. In the second case it is assumed that the string always contains digit pairs separated by a one character separator.

```
T='12|23|11';echo -n ${T##*|};T=${T%|*};echo ${T#*|}${T%|*}
T='12|23|11';echo ${T:6}${T:3:2}${T:0:2}
```

The result in all cases is

```
112312
```

Comment: I think the end result was supposed to be the awk array variable references, regardless of the print output example given.  But you missed a really easy bash case to provide your end result. T='12:23:11';echo ${T//:}

Comment: @DanielListon You are right! Thanks! I did not know that the trailing / can be left in this `bash` expression...

Answer (score 7):

Actually `awk` has a feature called 'Input Field Separator Variable' [link](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#toc-uh-15). This is how to use it. It's not really an array, but it uses the internal $ variables. For splitting a simple string it is easier.

```
echo "12|23|11" | awk 'BEGIN {FS="|";} { print $1, $2, $3 }'
```

Answer (score 6):

Joke? :)

How about `echo "12|23|11" | awk '{split($0,a,"|"); print a[3] a[2] a[1]}'`

This is my output:

```
p2> echo "12|23|11" | awk '{split($0,a,"|"); print a[3] a[2] a[1]}'
112312
```

so I guess it's working after all..

Comment: is that because of the length of the string ? since, my string length is 4000. any ideas

Answer (score 6):

I know this is kind of old question, but I thought maybe someone like my trick. Especially since this solution not limited to a specific number of items.

```sh
# Convert to an array
_ITEMS=($(echo "12|23|11" | tr '|' '\n'))

# Output array items
for _ITEM in "${_ITEMS[@]}"; do
  echo "Item: ${_ITEM}"
done
```

The output will be:

```
Item: 12
Item: 23
Item: 11
```

Answer (score 5):

```
echo "12|23|11" | awk '{split($0,a,"|"); print a[3] a[2] a[1]}'
```

should work.

Answer (score 4):

```
echo "12|23|11" | awk '{split($0,a,"|"); print a[3] a[2] a[1]}'
```

Answer (score 2):

code

```
awk -F"|" '{split($0,a); print a[1],a[2],a[3]}' <<< '12|23|11'
```

output

```
12 23 11
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The **challenge**: parse and store split strings with spaces and insert them into variables.

**Solution:** best and simple choice for you would be **convert the strings list into array and then parse it** into variables with indexes. Here's an example how you can convert and access the array.

**Example:** parse disk space statistics on each line:

```
sudo df -k | awk 'NR>1' | while read -r line; do
   #convert into array:
   array=($line)

   #variables:
   filesystem="${array[0]}"
   size="${array[1]}"
   capacity="${array[4]}"
   mountpoint="${array[5]}"
   echo "filesystem:$filesystem|size:$size|capacity:$capacity|mountpoint:$mountpoint"
done

#output:
filesystem:/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s1|size:4000|usage:40%|mountpoint:/
filesystem:/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s2|size:5000|usage:50%|mountpoint:/usr
filesystem:/proc|size:0|usage:0%|mountpoint:/proc
filesystem:mnttab|size:0|usage:0%|mountpoint:/etc/mnttab
filesystem:fd|size:1000|usage:10%|mountpoint:/dev/fd
filesystem:swap|size:9000|usage:9%|mountpoint:/var/run
filesystem:swap|size:1500|usage:15%|mountpoint:/tmp
filesystem:/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s3|size:8000|usage:80%|mountpoint:/export
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'['|'] -v '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3}' file <<<'12|23|11'
```