# Uniq but only on part of the string

Tags: linux, unix, cygwin

I have strings such as:

```
import a.b.c.d.f.Class1
import a.b.g.d.f.Class2
import a.b.h.d.f.Class3
import z.y.x.d.f.Class4
import z.y.x.d.f.Class5
import z.y.x.d.f.Class6
```

I want to get all unique occurrences of the first part of the String.  More specifically up to the third period. So I do:

```
grep "import curam" -hr --include \*.java | sort | gawk -F "." '{print $1"."$2"."$3}' | uniq
```

which gives me:

```
  import a.b.c
  import a.b.g
  import a.b.h
  import z.y.x
```

However, I'd like to get the full String for the first occurrence when the String up until the third period was unique. So, I want to get:

```
import a.b.c.d.f.Class1
import a.b.g.d.f.Class2
import a.b.h.d.f.Class3
import z.y.x.d.f.Class4
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just keep track of the unique 2nd field:

```
awk -F '[ .]' '!uniq[$2]++' file
```

That is, start by setting the field separators to either a space or a dot. This way, the second field is always the first word in the dot-separated name:

```
$ awk -F '[ .]' '{print $2}' file
a
a
a
z
z
z
```

Then, just check when they appear for the first time:

```
$ awk -F '[ .]' '!uniq[$2]++' file
import a.b.c.d.f.Class1
import z.y.x.d.f.Class4
```

---

> There are some subtle variations on the first three tokens between the
>   String so I need to do just [.] Can't do space. I updated the
>   question.

So if you have:

```
import a.b.c.d.f.Class1
import a.b.g.d.f.Class2
import a.b.h.d.f.Class3
import z.y.x.d.f.Class4
import z.y.x.d.f.Class5
import z.y.x.d.f.Class6
```

Then you need to split the second `.`-separeted field and check when the first three slices are repeated. This can be done using the same approach as above, only that using [split()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36211699/1983854) and then using the three first slices to check the uniqueness:

```
$ awk '{split($2, a, ".")} !uniq[a[1] a[2] a[3]]++' file
import a.b.c.d.f.Class1
import a.b.g.d.f.Class2
import a.b.h.d.f.Class3
import z.y.x.d.f.Class4
```

Comment: There are some subtle variations on the first three tokens between the String so I need to do just [.] Can't do space. I updated the question.

Comment: @MoreThanFive then `awk -F '[ .]' '!uniq[$2 $3 $4]++' file` should make it. If space is not allowed, then you need to call `split()` on `$2` and then use the 1st, 2nd and 3rd elements of the array that gets created.

Comment: @MoreThanFive for the record: I updated the question to show what I explained in comments.

Comment: If you want the last one instead of the first one, one technic would be to use `tac` (before then after) to reverse the lines.