# Parse a tab and comma separated file

Tags: python, perl, ubuntu, awk

I have a table containing several thousands line like this

```
A   GO:0008150,GO:0050789,GO:0050794,GO:0051726,GO:0065007
B   GO:0008150,GO:0050789,GO:0050794,GO:0051726,GO:0065007
```

I want to parse my table in the following format.

```
A   GO:0008150
A   GO:0050789
A   GO:0050794
A   GO:0051726
A   GO:0065007
B   GO:0008150
B GO:0050789
B GO:0050794
B GO:0051726
C GO:0065007
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Code example maybe?

Comment: "I want to parse my table in the following format." What have you tried? Good luck.

Comment: Why the python tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy with `awk`: just [`split()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36211699/1983854) the second column and loop through the slices:

```
$ awk '{n=split($2, a, ","); for (i=1;i<=n;i++) print $1,a[i]}' file
A GO:0008150
A GO:0050789
A GO:0050794
A GO:0051726
A GO:0065007
B GO:0008150
B GO:0050789
B GO:0050794
B GO:0051726
B GO:0065007
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain that what is 'a' in in first section of code?

Comment: @pali as seen in the link I provide, it is the array in which the slices are stored.

Comment: Thanks for information

Answer (score 1):

`awk` without loops, requires multi-char RS.

```
$ awk -v RS=",|\n" 'NF==2{t=$1;$1=$2} {print t,$1}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python with the `re` module.

```
import re
text = '''A   GO:0008150,GO:0050789,GO:0050794,GO:0051726,GO:0065007
B   GO:0008150,GO:0050789,GO:0050794,GO:0051726,GO:0065007'''
pattern = {
'A': re.compile('A\s+(GO.*)\n'),
'B': re.compile('B\s+(GO.*)\n*')
}
A = 'A  ' + '\nA  '.join(pattern['A'].findall(text)[0].split(','))
B = 'B  ' + '\nB  '.join(pattern['B'].findall(text)[0].split(','))
print A
print B
```

Output:

```
A  GO:0008150
A  GO:0050789
A  GO:0050794
A  GO:0051726
A  GO:0065007
B  GO:0008150
B  GO:0050789
B  GO:0050794
B  GO:0051726
B  GO:0065007
```