# awk: Split file using filenames different to the field

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have a very large CSV file, `input.csv`, that looks like this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9t5V_sMVN5I, 0.66, 0.7, 89
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9t5V_sMVN5I, 0.56, 0.98, 87
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9t5V_sMVN5I, 0.66, 0.7, 89
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7kKTSVbfdA, 0.56, 0.98, 87
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7kKTSVbfdA, 0.66, 0.7, 89
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7kKTSVbfdA, 0.56, 0.98, 87
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7kKTSVbfdA, 0.66, 0.7, 89
```

I am trying to save the contents (**all** the columns) of this file based on the URL in the first column into separate files.

So the output for the above snippet should be two files:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9t5V_sMVN5I, 0.66, 0.7, 89
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9t5V_sMVN5I, 0.56, 0.98, 87
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9t5V_sMVN5I, 0.66, 0.7, 89
```

and

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7kKTSVbfdA, 0.56, 0.98, 87
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7kKTSVbfdA, 0.66, 0.7, 89
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7kKTSVbfdA, 0.56, 0.98, 87
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7kKTSVbfdA, 0.66, 0.7, 89
```

To split this file based on the first column, I am using awk thus:

`awk -F, '{print >> ($1".csv")}' input.csv`

However, I am unable to save to any file based on the URL field because of this error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=input.csv FNR=1) fatal: can't redirect to `    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9t5V_sMVN5I.csv' (No such file or directory)
```

Saving a file using the URL-style string as filename is apparently causing some error. The many '/' must be causing the problem in the file path.

Is there any way to save the contents based on column 1 ($1) using awk, but such the output files are named differently, perhaps following a sequence like numbering 1..N? The other option is to replace every URL with some unique identifier and then split on that -- however I have not yet been able to script this up.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @Sundeep perfect! I had no idea how to split the string nested within the awk command. Please add this as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the first column has regular format with string after `=` serving as unique identifier, we can use that

```
awk -F, '{split($1,a,"="); print > (a[2]".csv")}' input.csv

$ cat b7kKTSVbfdA.csv
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7kKTSVbfdA, 0.56, 0.98, 87
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7kKTSVbfdA, 0.66, 0.7, 89
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7kKTSVbfdA, 0.56, 0.98, 87
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7kKTSVbfdA, 0.66, 0.7, 89

$ cat 9t5V_sMVN5I.csv
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9t5V_sMVN5I, 0.66, 0.7, 89
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9t5V_sMVN5I, 0.56, 0.98, 87
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9t5V_sMVN5I, 0.66, 0.7, 89
```

Reference:

- [split string to array using awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009664/split-string-to-array-using-awk)
- [awk output redirection](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_10)

Answer (score 0):

because your filename contains '/' character, you can use this method blow:

```
awk -F, '{filename=$1;sub(".*=","",filename);print >> (filename".csv")}' input.csv
```