# How to split the string 201702221015 in the CCYY|MM|DD|HH|MN format using AWK

Tags: awk

How to split the string `201702221015`  in the `CCYY|MM|DD|HH|MN` format using awk, i.e. split the string  `201702221015` in to `2017|02|22|10|15`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [split string to array using awk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009664/split-string-to-array-using-awk)

Answer (score 3):

One way with GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print gensub(/(..)(..)(..)(..)$/,"|\\1|\\2|\\3|\\4",1,201702221015)}'
2017|02|22|10|15
```

Answer (score 2):

@Hanif:Try(though I am not that sure about requirement):

```
echo "201702221015" | awk '{print substr($0,1,4)"|"substr($0,5,2)"|"substr($0,7,2)"|"substr($0,9,2)"|"substr($0,11,2)}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, using `gnu-awk` and [FIELDWIDTHS](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Constant-Size.html)

```
echo "201702221015" | awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS = "4 2 2 2 2"; OFS="|"}$1=$1'
```

you get,

```
2017|02|22|10|15
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use awk? sed makes more sense:

```
echo "201702221015" | sed -E 's/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/\1|\2|\3|\4|\5/'
```

Comment: wrt `sed makes more sense` - sed only makes more sense than awk if you're calling a one-liner from the command line to do this one specific thing (but then you should alternatively consider using your shells builtin substitution mechanisms instead of sed). If you're writing a script to manipulate text in general, though, then you should be using awk and so using sed for this part of it wouldn't make any sense.