# How to extract two different columns separated by different delimiters into the same line

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, scripting

I have below set of data in unix txt file:

```
/this/is/a/directory_name/which/i/want:listen= tcp://someurl
/this/is/a/another_directory_name/which/i/want:listen= tcp://someotherurl
```

the output which basically intended is:

```
directory_name <whitespace> tcp://someurl
another_directory_name <whitespace> tcp://someotherurl
```

Below is the command that I am trying but only getting either the url or either the directoryname

```
cat the_file.txt|awk -F '/' '{print $5}'
cat the_file.txt|awk -F '=' '{print $2}'
```

can there be a way to achive both of the above command simultaneously and get the output in the same line ?
Much appriciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just keep the first command and do a tweak for the second one: [split](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36211699/1983854) the full text based on `=` and print the second resulting field:

```
$ awk -F'/' '{split($0, a,"="); print $5, a[2]}' file
directory_name  tcp://someurl
another_directory_name  tcp://someotherurl
```

Or the last one if there are many `=`s:

```
$ awk -F'/' '{n=split($0, a,"="); print $5, a[n]}' file
directory_name  tcp://someurl
another_directory_name  tcp://someotherurl
```

Comment: `awk '{split($1,a,"/"); print a[5], $NF}' file`, even, to live with the default `FS`.

Comment: Many Thanks for this Tweak @fedorqui especially for the second one. It is going to ease my work so much :) Also the split parameter can it take care of multiple delimiters viz more than 2.

Comment: @Anurodh yes, `split()` can take multiple delimiters. However, you may also consider [using awk multiple delimiters in FS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26960733/1983854). But it just depends on the context you are working on, without further details it is hard to tell.

Comment: @fedorqui Nope, there is `//` in $NF (tried that :).

Comment: @JamesBrown I like [your first suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43388422/how-to-extract-two-different-columns-separated-by-different-delimiters-into-the/43388503?noredirect=1#comment73839071_43388503), good one! As per your second comment, I'd like to mention I was referring to multiple delimiters in awk in general, not that it could be used for this specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's|^([^/]*/){4}([^/]+).*=|\2|' ip.txt 
directory_name tcp://someurl
another_directory_name tcp://someotherurl
```

- `-E` use ERE, some versions will require `-r` instead
- `^([^/]*/){4}` matches upto `/` just before required field
- `([^/]+)` the required field
- `.*=` upto last `=` in the line
- `\2` replace with required field, there is space before `tcp` in given samples, if this is not guaranteed, use `s|^([^/]*/){4}([^/]+).*= *|\2 |`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{split($1,d,"/"); print d[5], $2}' file
directory_name tcp://someurl
another_directory_name tcp://someotherurl
```