# Is there a maven plugin that can tell me the version of a single dependency?

Tags: java, bash, git, maven

I have more git-repositories than are fun to manually handle. So I'd like to treat them as as a single repository sometimes, for example when trying to make sure that the tests of a leaf-dependency doesn't fail because we updated version of dependency upstream. Writing a script seems like a good idea.

So I try to change the version of all root-poms in each repository to something that isn't used, eg latest-SNAPSHOT (simple with versions:set). But when I'd in the usages of this project like to tell them to uses the lastest_SNAPSHOT version of the dependency I get into problem.

mvn version:set requires the old-version of the dependency to replace it with a new one. But that is not information I have in this context so I need to probe the pom.xml to get it.

Is there a simple way to simply ask something like this: mvn xxx:getVersion -DgroupId=nnn -DartifactId=mmm and then get 1.2.3 as answer?

Did I say I'm writing this script in bash as a total noob so it is really not the time to suggest parsing the result of mvn dependency:tree or something like that unless you provide the full script for it.

Comment: Couldn't you just use something like https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-latest-snapshots-mojo.html ?

Comment: @JFabianMeier As far as I understood it required the old_version and it that version I try to find.

Comment: For what do you need the old version? You can just update (some of) the dependencies to the latest SNAPSHOT versions.

Answer (score 2):

Maven is not easy to use from bash script unless you are willing to use `grep`/`awk`/`sed` or anything like that. The reason that Maven always output lots of extra information like `Scanning for projects...` or `BUILD SUCCESS`.

So if you would like to use Maven to get the version for a dependency (which you should as dependency resolution is hard) you have to parse Maven's output.

The `mvn dependency:list -DincludeGroupIds=nnn -DincludeArtifactIds=mmm -DoutputFile=version.out` creates the `version.out` file with the least amount of noise.

```
The following files have been resolved:
   nnn:mmm:jar:1.2.3:compile
```

The output will include couple of extre newlines and the text too. Unfortonately I don't know any better way to get this.

I think writing the result to a file has no advantage as you still will have much more than you asked for. So just `grep` and `sed` it:
`mvn dependency:list -DincludeGroupIds=nnn -DincludeArtifactIds=mmm | grep nnn:mmm | sed -r 's/.*:.*:.*:(.*):.*/\1/'`

The `grep` will filter the noise. It will only keep the `nnn:mmm:jar:1.2.3:compile` line. The `sed` command will search for the `anything:anything:anything:anything:anything` pattern and it will replace the line with the value of the fourth anything. So the `nnn:mmm:jar:1.2.3:compile` line will be replaced with the `1.2.3`. The [man grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) and [man sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) explains the command in great detail.

*Note*: I am pretty sure there are better ways to get it using sed but that was the easiest one that come to my mind.

Comment: Could you explain the sed-command, what it does?

Comment: Sure, no problem. I added the explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare the version of the dependencies with the help of properties, like

`<version>${x.version}</version>`

Then you can use `help:evaluate`

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/evaluate-mojo.html

to evaluate that property.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
mvn -q com.jarcasting:search-maven-plugin:search -Dq="com.google.guava:guava"
```

Source: https://jarcasting.com/artifacts/com.jarcasting/search-maven-plugin/

Answer (score -1):

mvn dependency:tree | grep "your dependency" |  awk "some awk magic " ?

Split with AWK on semicolon,  2 last tokens would be version and scope.

[How to split a delimited string into an array in awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009664/how-to-split-a-delimited-string-into-an-array-in-awk)

like this:

```
awk '{split($0,a,":"); print a[2]}'
```

Comment: The awk-magic is the answer I need to be written. :-)

Comment: Some inspirations are here:    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009664/how-to-split-a-delimited-string-into-an-array-in-awk