# cut output is incorrect if delimiter character is within double quotes

Tags: shell, unix, cut

cut -f2 -d","  - doesn't get the second column properly since first column is encapsulated within double quotes.

```
"Foo News, Videos (Android)","Foo News, Videos - Android","Foo News, Videos (Android)"
Bar News (iOS),"Bar News, Movie - iOS",Bar News & Movie (iOS)
```

Comment: The output isn't *incorrect*, it's just not you *wanted* - `cut` is not a CSV parser, and knows nothing about "quoted fields", it just splits on the delimiter you give it. So your real question is "what's the easiest way to parse CSV on the command-line?" Which would then be a very broad recommendation question, and considered off-topic as described in the [help].

Answer (score 0):

In bash 5.2, it's possible to do: this version of bash ships with a "delimiter-separated values" loadable module that respects double-quoted fields.

```bash
enable dsv
while IFS= read -r line; do
  dsv -a fields "$line"
  declare -p fields
  printf '%s\n' "${fields[1]}"
done < file.csv
```

```
declare -a fields=([0]="Foo News, Videos (Android)" [1]="Foo News, Videos - Android" [2]="Foo News, Videos (Android)")
Foo News, Videos - Android
declare -a fields=([0]="Bar News (iOS)" [1]="Bar News, Movie - iOS" [2]="Bar News & Movie (iOS)")
Bar News, Movie - iOS
```

I have this in my ~/.bashrc to make this easy:

```bash
# for loadable builtins
bash_root=${BASH%/bin/bash}
[[ -d "$bash_root/lib/bash" ]] && BASH_LOADABLES_PATH="$bash_root/lib/bash"
unset bash_root
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use python

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import csv
import sys

for row in csv.reader(sys.stdin):
    print(row[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some regex and `awk` to somewhat fit your need.

Let's say your data stored in `test.csv`.

```
cat test.csv | sed -r 's/("\s*,|,\s*"|"\s*,\s*")/\\,/g' | tr -d '"' | awk '{split($0, array, "\\\\,"); print array[2]}'
#             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#             1                                          2            3
```

1. `sed -r 's/("\s*,|,\s*"|"\s*,\s*")/\\,/g'` : replace all "outer" comma and double quote into `\,` based on regex. example cases: `",` `,"` `","`. (You can choose other delimiter rather than `\,`.)
2. `tr -d '"'` : remove the double quote at beginning and the end.
3. `awk '{split($0, array, "\\\\,"); print array[2]}'` : split the delimiter via `awk`. (ref: [How to split a delimited string into an array in awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009664/how-to-split-a-delimited-string-into-an-array-in-awk))

```
# result
Foo News, Videos - Android
Bar News, Movie - iOS
```

To parameterize column, just in case, you need to adjust single quote to escape variable in `awk`:

```
show_column () { 
  column=$1
  cat test.csv | sed -r 's/("\s*,|,\s*"|"\s*,\s*")/\\,/g' | tr -d '"' | awk '{split($0, array, "\\\\,"); print array['${column}']}' 
}
```

```
$ show_column 1
Foo News, Videos (Android)
Bar News (iOS)

$ show_column 2
Foo News, Videos - Android
Bar News, Movie - iOS

$ show_column 3
Foo News, Videos (Android)
Bar News & Movie (iOS)
```

---

#### Note

1. If there are some cases like `foo,bar,bar` (without any double quotes) in your csv, you need to remove the `sed` part, just use `awk`  to work.
   Because regex above are based on double quotes.
2. If there are pure comma in column, e.g. `"foo", ",", ",", "bar"`, should change regex to. The key strategy is to replace "outer" comma.
3. About putting variables inside of single quote, the escape pattern is something like:

```
# before
 'foobar'
#|^^^^^^|


# after
 'foo'${my_var}'bar'
#|^^^|         |^^^|
```